# Difference (XOR) between two rectangles, as rectangles?

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I'm looking for a simple way to calculate the difference between two rectangles. I mean all points which belong to one of the rectangles, but not to both (so it's like XOR).

The rectangles are axis-aligned in this case, so there will be only right angles. I believe the difference region can be expressed in 0-4 rectangles (0 if both rectangles are the same, 1 if just one edge is different, 4 in the general case), and I'd like to get the difference region as a list of rectangles.

You can also think of it as the areas of the screen that have to be updated when a solid rectangle is moved/resized.

Examples: Doubling the width of rectangle "a" - I want the added region (R).

```
+----+----+
| a  | R  |
|    |    |
+----+----+
```

Intersecting rectangles (a and b) - I want the area given by T, L, R and B in rectangles (other partitioning possible), but excluding X:

```
+------------+  a
|      T     |
|·····+------+-----+  b
|  L  | X    |  R  |
|     |      |     |
+-----+------+·····|
      |    B       |
      +------------+
```

I'd prefer a python solution/library, but any robust algorithm would be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Split the problem down onto a per-axis basis. Your rectangles can be defined in terms of their spans on each axis - find the interesting points on each axis where a rectangle starts or ends and then define your results in those terms. This'll give you 6 rectangles of difference areas, you can easily combine them down to the four you've illustrated or eliminate degenerate zero-area rectangles if you need to.

Here's a Java implementation:

```
public class Rect
{
    private float minX, maxX, minY, maxY;

    public Rect( float minX, float maxX, float minY, float maxY )
    {
        this.minX = minX;
        this.maxX = maxX;
        this.minY = minY;
        this.maxY = maxY;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the difference between two intersecting rectangles
     * 
     * @param r
     * @param s
     * @return An array of rectangle areas that are covered by either r or s, but
     *         not both
     */
    public static Rect[] diff( Rect r, Rect s )
    {
        float a = Math.min( r.minX, s.minX );
        float b = Math.max( r.minX, s.minX );
        float c = Math.min( r.maxX, s.maxX );
        float d = Math.max( r.maxX, s.maxX );

        float e = Math.min( r.minY, s.minY );
        float f = Math.max( r.minY, s.minY );
        float g = Math.min( r.maxY, s.maxY );
        float h = Math.max( r.maxY, s.maxY );

        // X = intersection, 0-7 = possible difference areas
        // h ┌─┬─┬─┐
        // . │5│6│7│
        // g ├─┼─┼─┤
        // . │3│X│4│
        // f ├─┼─┼─┤
        // . │0│1│2│
        // e └─┴─┴─┘
        // . a b c d

        Rect[] result = new Rect[ 6 ];

        // we'll always have rectangles 1, 3, 4 and 6
        result[ 0 ] = new Rect( b, c, e, f );
        result[ 1 ] = new Rect( a, b, f, g );
        result[ 2 ] = new Rect( c, d, f, g );
        result[ 3 ] = new Rect( b, c, g, h );

        // decide which corners
        if( r.minX == a && r.minY == e || s.minX == a && s.minY == e )
        { // corners 0 and 7
            result[ 4 ] = new Rect( a, b, e, f );
            result[ 5 ] = new Rect( c, d, g, h );
        }
        else
        { // corners 2 and 5
            result[ 4 ] = new Rect( c, d, e, f );
            result[ 5 ] = new Rect( a, b, g, h );
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an algorithm in this link:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Rectangle_difference

It is called "4-zone Rectangle Difference".

It basically computes the four possible rectangles that may remain after subtracting one rectangle from other.

In this case, the algorithm have to be run twice.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine finding the area of the intersecting rectangle (that is X) and deducting that from the combined area of rectangle a + rectangle b will give your solution.

I found this on my hunt for a quick answer:

http://tekpool.wordpress.com/2006/10/12/rectangle-intersection-find-the-intersecting-rectangle/