# Math for counting the difference of concentric rectangles

Tags: math, geometry, cartesian

I have 2 rectangles, one which is basically the other scaled up, like so
[image]

I'd like to see if a set of xy coords falls within the XOR difference, ie

[image]

What's the best math to do this?

[Difference (XOR) between two rectangles, as rectangles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144615/difference-xor-between-two-rectangles-as-rectangles) does kind of what I want, but not exactly, and it seems somewhat... inelegant.

Alternately, I could work with something that returns "true" if x/y coords are within 10% of the edge of the outer rectangle

Comment: Why does your question title talk about "counting"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool isInIntersection(pt, rect1, rect2)
{
    return isInRect(pt, rect1) && !isInRect(pt, rect2);
}

bool isInRect(pt, rect)
{
    return (pt.x >= rect.x1) && (pt.x < rect.x2)
        && (pt.y >= rect.y1) && (pt.y < rect.y2);
}
```

where I'm assuming `rect1` is the outer rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example in javascript for finding if a point is in a rectangle. [Point-in-rectangle testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802013/point-in-rectangle-testing) 
 Then its just a matter if testing if its in Rectangle1 and if so, if its not in Rectangle2.